# Eclipse compiler error/warnings preferences

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I've been wondering if there is such a thing as an optimal compiler error/warning configuration to "force" your code to be less bug prone.
I know many people tweak those configurations for their needs. But, there has to be a "complete" set of preferences like the one for VIM editor in Linux.

Does anyone know a good set of preferences or where to find one?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few Eclipse plugins that check your code. I don't know what language you develop in but for Java here are a few plugins I know of:

1. [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) - Comprehensive checklist that can be configured based on what you think is important or not
2. [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) - Similar to above, personally I found PMD to cover a lot more

I don't know of a recommended set of preferences, if that's what you are looking for I guess  you can ignore this answer.

Comment: PMD is not what I want. I did give FindBugs a go found it very hard to work with, not very user friendly and NO hotkey!
In the end I started with setting everything to an `Error` level and changing settings as I go according to project standards. It's working good so far.